# How can I add a Header/Navbar and Footer to a fullscreen webpage that is scroll-snapped?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out how I can create a fullscreen webpage that uses scroll-snap to scroll up and down (with indicators, though I haven't figured out the JS for it yet) with a header or navbar and a footer portion. I've been able to get a fullscreen scroll-snap page, but the navbar and footer kind of mess with it.

Here is my base code, and I don't really know how to build on from here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 3vw);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Section One</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Section Two</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Section Three</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Section Four</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Section Five</h1>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want your first `section` to have `100vh` *including* the navbar and the last `section` to include the `footer`?

Answer (score 0):

scroll-padding is used to adjust the effective viewable region of the scroll container.It is used when calculating scroll snap alignments. The property defines an inset against the scroll container's padding box.

```
<article>
  <header> Header </header>
  <section> Section One </section>
  <section> Section Two </section>
  <section> Section Three </section>
</article>
```

```
article {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
  scroll-padding-top: 15vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
}
```